# Render HTML markup got from backend in JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, axios, react-props

I'm trying to render HTML that coming from request as a string. I've tried passing it as a props and render this props directly in JSX. Nothing worked. I'm not sure if i need to use renderProps or dangerouslySetInnerHTML. But i really don't want to refer directly to DOM

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class SomePageComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    stateData: ''
  }
  
  componentDidMount = async() => {
    const { request } = this.props
    await request().then(data => this.setState({
        stateData: data
      })
    )
  }
  render() {
  const { stateData } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
       //so i need to put it somwhere here and i tried like tis below
         <div>{stateData}</div>
      //aslo i've tried like this
        <stateData />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

`

Comment: [dangerouslysetinnerhtml](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings is there any other methods to do this? Refering directly to the DOM is a bad pattern

Comment: @Vladislav this is THE method to render string to html in React. As the prop name says, it is DANGEROUS, because you don't have control on the string you are rendering as HTML, and this is independent of how you render it.